# How to understand "you've had it bad" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> ‘Personally, I'd have welcomed a dementor attack. A deadly struggle for my soul would have broken the monotony nicely. You think **you've had it bad**, at least you've been able to get out and about, stretch your legs, get into a few fights.... I've been stuck inside for a month.’
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*</sub>

"[have(got) it bad](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-got-it-bad)" means *to be very much in love* according to Cambridge. It doesn't seem to fit for this particular context. However, that's the only meaning I found in dictionaries. How should we understand "*you've had it bad*" in this context? In my opinion, it can probably be paraphrased as "*You take it as a bad thing for you.*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, "you've had it bad" means "you have been subject to bad conditions and experiences".  See the [Oxford Dictionaries entry](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/have_got_it_bad_(or_badly)), specifically sense 1.1.